# Run IE 7 explorer

Tags: installation, ie

my web application is run at IE 7.  Now is it possible to run this web application in Ubuntu desktop using IE 7?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `wine` for this.

Follow this [link](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=22194) to the wine website, where you can see that Ubuntu 12.04 works with this specific Internet Explorer version. But it must be exactly that version.

Install `wine` with:

```
apt-get install wine
```